# Which is the best viewBox canvas aspect-ratio for an icon set

Tags: svg, icon, typesetting

I've noticed that different SVG icon sets use different aspect ratios for the canvas (the viewBox on SVG).

- Font Awesome seems to use: 7:8. ([source](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/6.x/svgs/regular/bell.svg))
- Entypo use 5:4. ([source](https://github.com/danielbruce/entypo/blob/master/src/svg/bell.svg?short_path=46056cc))
- Typicons and Bootstrap use 1:1. ([source](https://github.com/stephenhutchings/typicons.font/blob/master/src/svg/bell.svg?short_path=c2307a3) and [source](https://github.com/twbs/icons/blob/main/icons/bell.svg?short_path=585d417))

Is there any good reason to chose one over the other? What impact will it have when using it on a web-page, for example for alignment with fonts, as the aspect ratio of the font is almost always no square.